# ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(946) handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -202 on android

Tags: android

I have converted a web application into the android app using capacitor, My APIs are running on HTTPS mode, but when I try to reach the APIs I am getting below error.

```
      [ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(946)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -202
```

I don't no, where I did the mistake,

my AndroidMainfest.xml

```
  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```

network_security_config.xml

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
          <network-security-config>
          <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
          <domain includeSubdomains="true">api.**.*****.com</domain>
          </domain-config>
          </network-security-config>
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @EduardoRoth No...I didn't found

Comment: did yu find any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

update "Android System Webview" app from Google play

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In addition to your network_security_config.xml I added certificate used for the API, .cer in my case (.pfx for the API), like described below in section "Configure a custom CA":
https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config